# Where can I find a graph of average transactions per block over time?

Tags: transactions, block, charts

Is there a website where I can view the size of the memory pool over time, or the average number of transactions per block?

Comment: For the size of the memory pool you are referring to the number of transactions the node knows of but not yet included in a block?

Answer (score 6):

For a chart of the average number of transactions per block per day:

- http://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions-per-block